# How to choose between different if conditions depending on another variable

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I've been thinking about this problem for some time, but i just can't think of a solution without having to write duplicate code. The problem in part c# and part pseudo-code:

```
bool test = true;  
if (test == true)
{
    if(first condition) {code}
}
else
{
    if(different condition) {same code as above)
}
```

I have to use this part in a performance intensive part of my program and i'd have to transfer 3 big parameters, which is why i'd rather not use a method.

Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: think of moving your *code* to a function/method

Comment: You could put the contents of `code` in a function and call it from both inner conditions.

Comment: So.. `if((test && fcondition) || dcondition) { //code }`

Comment: Be aware that `if(test = true)` always evaluates to true.

Comment: I know it's always true, but this is just an example. The real code is more complex.
I have to use this part in a performance intensive part of my program and i'd have to transfer 3 big parameters, which is why i'd rather not use a method.

Comment: You could just use a lambda instead.

Comment: What is a big parameter? A big struct ? Also where is the problem creating a function, unless you run in debug, the code should be inlined. Or is it too complex?

Comment: Declare additional boolean variable with initial `false` value, set it to true in `if` conditions. After outer `if` check the value of variable and execute the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ((test && first_condition) || (!test && different_condition)) {
    callSomeFunction();
}
```

Comment: The `different_condition` is when `!test` so that doesn't make sense.  That would leave exactly what OP has.  Unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Hardly can understand why exactly the same answer by @Lee posted later than this one gets positive votes and this one gets negative ones. Except the fact that you missed `)`.

Comment: I don't understand either, but I originally had `test == true` but simplified it in a quick edit, maybe people saw that.  Added the `)`, thanks.

Comment: Accepted this since this was faster than the other same answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
if((test && firstCondition) || (!test && differentCondition)) {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
// create an inline function to capture the  
Action workAction = () => { //work; }

bool test = true;  
if (test == true)
{
    if(first condition) {workAction(); }
}
else
{
    if(different condition) {workAction(); ) 
}
```

Comment: Well, except for abstracting the work as an action. Compound logic statements are tricky to get right, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of the conditions, this approach can sometimes help:

```
bool doBigCall = false;
if (test1)
{
    if (test2)
    {
        doBigCall = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
else
{
    // ...
}
if (doBigCall)
{
    // write the big bit of code just once
}
```